# App crash when call Vidyo Connection disable() function

Tags: android, vidyo

I use Vidyo connector in `Fragment` and follow the guide within `Activity`, I do the same with my fragment :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    ...
    mVidyoConnector.disable();
    ...
}
```

But the app crash with unknown reason. The logcat show last line:

|ERROR   |VidyoClient    |[System thread]|CrashHandler: 
    No stack trace.

Any one has same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please focus on disconnect() API. It's asynchronous call which is following to onDisconencted() callback so if you trigger it right before activity exit this will lead to crash because from onDestroy() you are releasing client with disable().

Imagine like you are starting disconnection process (which take some amount of time) and at the same time releasing all the resources/drop connections.

Call to disconnect only from user interaction perspective (via UI button) and once received onDisconnected() -> quit activity here (with finish) which will cause onDestroy() and release client.
Same you can handle via onBackPressed().